# Beep with volume set for ringtones

Tags: android

I need do a beep, using the set volume STREAM_RING.

I see the class ToneGenerator, but, in constructor, this class not receive the volume of AudioManager.STREAM_RING ...

In my device, range of volume is 1-7.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Mateus

Comment: I solve this... Thanks brothers.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate tone with maximum volume.

```
ToneGenerator toneGenerator= new   ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
    //this will play tone for 2 seconds.
toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1, 2000);
```